# Error getting last 3 rows from mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to get the last 3 rows from a query but I keep getting this error:

SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'id'

Please, what am I doing wrong here?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT i.*, m.*, p.* FROM message i JOIN 
members m ON m.id = i.sender_id JOIN profile_photos p 
ON p.member_id = m.id   WHERE (receiver_id = :receive 
AND sender_id = :sent OR receiver_id = :sent AND sender_id = :receive) 
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 3) t ORDER BY date ASC";
```

Comment: My guess is that `i` or `p` has a column named `id`

Comment: Please show your database schema

Comment: You have duplicates in the `select i.*, m.*, p.*`.  List only the columns that you actually want.

Comment: Up voted  @GordonLinoff comment. Wildcars imho are never a good idea while selecting the fields to output and can cause massive resources usage or undesirable behavior of the queries like this one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably already have `ID` column in more than one table and select statement `SELECT i.*, m.*, p.*` listing them all.

Either choose the specific column you want like

```
SELECT i.id, i.col1, m.col2, p.col3 ...
```

OR, use a column alias like

```
SELECT i.id as IID, m.*, p.id as PID
```

Comment: Thank you! I choose the specific fields I needed